# Regular expression for having a hyphen between 2 digits

Tags: java, regex

I want to ensure that the pattern matches the following input only :

- 123( a digit )
- 123-89 (or a digit followed by a hyphen and a digit, that is only one hyphen between 2 digits)

I tried the pattern  `((\\d)+(-)?(\\d)*)`

however, it does matches input like `41-`. i want to avoid input like: `-41` (which starts with hyphen) or ends `41-` with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Try out `(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?`

I tried this in [regexpal](http://regexpal.com) and it matched your inputs.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the second `\d`

Comment: @Barmar I meant to put the parenthesis outside the `+`, my apologies

Comment: @BoristheSpider I was assuming he wanted to capture the digits, thus the capture brackets

Comment: Make that clear in your answer then, as if the OP it not wanting to capture then they are just serving to slow down the regex engine. From my reading the OP just wants to validate a format.

Comment: @BoristheSpider from my reading he wants to capture the digits, since he has parenthesis around the `\\d`...

Comment: You reckon the OP also wants to capture the hyphen?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I figured yes he wanted to capture the hyphen to see if the hyphen was there or not. So yes I *reckon* that. Do note that if you're attempting to be condescending it's really unappreciated.

Comment: Nope, just trying to figure out your logic. If that's your theory, you probably need to explain that the OP can just check for the presence of the second match group. P.S. what makes you think the OP is male?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Are you really still arguing this? What is your goal here?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, in Java syntax:

```
\\d++(?:-\\d++)?
```

The first part, `\\d++`, possessively grabs the starting digits. At least on is required.

The second part `(?:-\\d++)` is a non-capturing group that matches `-` followed by one or more digits. Again, possessively. The `?` makes this entire group optional.

Answer (score 0):

I just separate the 2 cases with a |

```
((\d+)|(\d+-\d+))
```

Comment: @Boris the Spider, I tried this: \\d++(?:-\\d++)?
but it does match 21- or -21
i want the pattern to avoid accepting such input

Answer (score 0):

I'm only posting this because other answers are all longer than needed.  Try this:

```
\\d+(-\\d+)?
```